# How do I sort result of find command by file size, and display the file sizes (in MB)?

Tags: bash, sorting, grep, find, xargs

As an auxiliary question, it'd be nice to know how to make the output look neat as well (does bash have some form of string formatting?)  Anyways, I have a find . command returning all files over a certain size, and I want to sort those results in descending order and pipe them to a mailer.  I have the mailing part down, but I'm not sure how to sort them and display the file sizes in an organized manner.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: in `man find` you can find a parameter to print the size of the files. By printing them somewhere in your result you can then pipe to `sort`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will find all files > 1000 bytes and print out the filename and size (in bytes):

```
$ find tmp/ -size +1000c -printf '%p %s\n' | sort -k2 -n
```

Which would give you output like:

```
tmp/gitwork/integration/.git/hooks/pre-rebase.sample 4951
tmp/gitwork/repo1/.git/hooks/pre-rebase.sample 4951
tmp/gitwork/repo2/.git/hooks/pre-rebase.sample 4951
tmp/gitwork/upstream1/hooks/pre-rebase.sample 4951
tmp/gitwork/upstream2/hooks/pre-rebase.sample 4951
tmp/constraints.dot 7035
tmp/constraints.svg 41657
tmp/so31567373/KBFI.xml 375557
tmp/overflow.tar 399360
```

If you want to make this "pretty", you could add some field-width specifiers to that `printf` directive:

```
$ find tmp/ -size +1000c -printf '%-60p %s\n' | sort -k2 -n
```

Which would get you:

```
tmp/gitwork/integration/.git/hooks/pre-rebase.sample         4951
tmp/gitwork/repo1/.git/hooks/pre-rebase.sample               4951
tmp/gitwork/repo2/.git/hooks/pre-rebase.sample               4951
tmp/gitwork/upstream1/hooks/pre-rebase.sample                4951
tmp/gitwork/upstream2/hooks/pre-rebase.sample                4951
tmp/constraints.dot                                          7035
tmp/constraints.svg                                          41657
tmp/so31567373/KBFI.xml                                      375557
tmp/overflow.tar                                             399360
```

If your definition of "pretty" requires something more complex, you may want to investigate piping the output through `awk`.

Comment: Is there a way of converting the size to MB?  I mean I know the conversion factor is 10^6, but is there some way of utilizing that information?

Comment: I think this would fall into the "pipe the output through awk" case. Awk can do basic arithmetic, so prettifying the numbers would be relatively easy.